# How display result of multi select in PgAdmin III?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

```
select 1 as a,4 as b, 5 as c;
select 1 as a,3 as b;
```

Result display only of  `select 1 as a,3 as b;

How display result of multi select in PgAdmin III?`

Comment: pgAdmin can display only last result - btw PostgreSQL doesn't support multi record sets - It support multi selects, but result is only last result

Answer (score 3):

One **way around this limitation** would be [**`UNION ALL`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION).

However, the **row type** of all `SELECTs` has **has to match**. So I added `NULL` for the missing column `c` in the second query. Could be any value that fits the data type:

```
SELECT 1 AS a, 4 AS b, 5 AS c FROM tbl_a
UNION ALL
SELECT 1     , 3     , NULL   FROM tbl_b;  -- aliases only needed in 1st SELECT
```

Returns a *single* result set.

To indicate the source of each row you could add a column or slide in a row between individual SELECTs. Demonstrating both at once with VALUES expressions:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   VALUES
      (1, 1, 14, 15)
     ,(1, 2, 17, 11)
   ) AS t(query, a, b, c)

UNION ALL VALUES (NULL::int, NULL::int, NULL::int, NULL::int) -- delimiter

UNION ALL (
   VALUES
      (2, 3, 24, NULL::int)
     ,(2, 4, 27, NULL::int)
   );
```

Explicit type casts may be necessary. I only added what's absolutely necessary here.
[**->SQLfiddle** demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1243)